# How to add Layered Navigation On Brand View Page

Tags: custom, layered-navigation, magento2.3.1

I'm using free Magento2.3 "Magetop_Brand" Ext. which is working fine but i want to call layered navigation on brand view page...how can i achieve?

[image]

[image]

**Ext. URL:-**

https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-shop-by-brand-extension.html

Thanks!!!

Comment: Follow below link it may help you.   https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-layered-navigation-on-custom-page-in-magento-2/